# WindowsIdentity.GetAnonymous()

Tags: .net, windows-identity

Could you please explain me what is the anonymous identity used for? As far as I know windows does not have an anonymous account type ?!

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous user is usually mapped to a guest account, or can be associated in IIS with any account you choose in order to control permissions for an unauthenticated user.

Comment: Could you please explain it to me in a more detailed way? Also when would I call GetAnonymous method?

Comment: Please try this link, which explains it fairly well. 
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9a756c07-de03-4754-94d6-df69fc3bb657.mspx?mfr=true